# My question is flagged as being potentially subjective and therefore liable to be closed. Opinions please

Tags: discussion

I have a 'soft' question as follows:

> *'How did you first become interested in becoming a mathematician?'*
>
> The sort of answers I'm seeking are factual rather than subjective,
>   e.g.
>
> *I first became interested in mathematics when I heard about Fermat's Last Theorem at the age of 11. At that moment I decided I would keep trying until I solved it.*
>
> or
>
> *I was the best in my class at arithmetic and I enjoyed finding new and quicker ways of performing calculations*.

As this is my first question on MO, I don't want to start badly.

**Questions**

1. Is the above question suitable for the site?
2. If not, can it be improved to be so?
3. If neither of the above, where is a good place to ask professional mathematicians what inspired them to take up their careers?

Comment: I'd say this question is rather not suitable for this site -- even more if someone asks it as their first question here. If you "don't want to start badly", I think the best advice is to start either with an interesting non-soft question or with giving a good answer to a question of someone else.

Comment: I'm not at all enthusiastic about the question either, but if you'd like some idea of what inspired various individuals to make a career of mathematics, I'd recommend the collections of interviews *Mathematical People* and *More Mathematical People*.

Comment: I'm going to agree; while this might make a suitable sort of discussion for a different kind of forum, I don't think it is suitable for a site that is meant to be for discussing research-level mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You have convinced me. Additionally Todd Trimble has given me a lead that hopefully will make my intended question unnecessary.

Comment: I just learned of this, which seems to be a companion volume to the other books I mentioned: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tondeur/Albers-2011.pdf